# Instructions for LEGO bag 135149

Tags: instructions, set-identification

Can someone please help me find the instructions for LEGO bag 135149? The bag says 2011 and has a propeller-type brick and a white helmet?   Any clues what this is?

Comment: That bag number is the generic item code for the plastic bag only, not for the contents. All LEGO bags (with a few exceptions) will have that item code and 2011 as the year. But, if you post pictures of the bag and its contents, we can help you identify the set it came from.

Comment: Is this a polybag or a boxed set? This would make it easier to find the set you are looking for. Although I'm not quite sure what set this, you can always try using letsbuilditagain.com, brickset, brickowl, or lego.com for instructions.

Answer (score 2):

By using the [Brickset list of polybags released by Lego in 2011](http://brickset.com/sets/tag-polybag/year-2011), I think your bag may refer to the following: [30014-1: Police Helicopter](http://brickset.com/sets/30014-1/Police-Helicopter).