# I have bags 2 and 3 of the LEGO group 2011 but no instructions, can anyone identify these?

Tags: set-identification, instructions

[image][image]

I have bags 2 and 3 with the number 135149 on them but didn’t get instructions (found them at goodwill). They have red, brown and green, some gray and black bricks, with guns, a cowboy, an Indian, a cowgirl, a horse and others.

Comment: The bag date and number are for the bag, not the set FYI - see comment [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7224/instructions-for-lego-bag-135149)

Comment: Thank you! First time really getting into legos now that I have a little boy that’s interested!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like set [79108](https://rebrickable.com/sets/79108-1/stagecoach-escape/) Stagecoach Escape by matching the horse, saddle and the minifig head.